# How to model cassandra table to allow where clause on a non primary key

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, spring-data-cassandra

I am using `cassandra` in an experimental project. My model is simple I have the table below:

```
create table message(
id varchar,
msgId varchar,
tId varchar,
gtName varchar,
status varchar,
text text,
PRIMARY KEY (id, tId)

);
```

At the time of first insert I would only have id and tId to insert. There will be an immediate update where I can get msgId to persist from the return type of the called method. There will be another call to my app containing the `status` which would only know the msgId. In that case I will need a lookup in order to update the message table using a `where clause on msgId`.

How can I possibly get that working fine with `cassandra 2.1.0` I am also using `spring-data-cassandra:1.1.0.RELEASE`

Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

A first simple step would be to create a [secondary index](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/create_index_r.html) on that key:

```
create index on message(msgId);
select * from message where msgId='foo';
```

Secondary indexes do have some performance concerns and aren't always a good fit, depending on your data model. Another option is to create a second table which maps `msgId` back to `id` and `tId`:

```
create table msgid (
     msgId varchar,
     id varchar,
     tId varchar,
     primary key (msgId)
);
```

Here are some useful discussions about usage of secondary indexes:

- [Cassandra query on secondary index is very slow - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093181/cassandra-query-on-secondary-index-is-very-slow)
- [The sweet spot for Cassandra secondary indexing - Richard Low's blog](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77)
- [How to avoid secondary indexes in cassandra? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124993/how-to-avoid-secondary-indexes-in-cassandra)

Comment: Thanks a lot, checking the links